# Spyder on my mac recently stopped working and gives me error messages to the terminal as soon as I launch it

Tags: macos, spyder

I'm running High Sierra on my Mac. I have python versions 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.  I have conda environments for each version. I had been using Spyder 3.3.2 a lot and really liked it. Recently however it stopped working. Best I can recall the problems started when I tried upgrading to Spyder 4.0.  I've deleted Anaconda and reloaded it to no avail. I've tried it on Python 2.7 and 3.6 and I get the same error messages.

What I've tried: Uninstall and install spyder. I've reloaded pyqt and it loaded with no errors. I deleted and reinstalled Anaconda.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?  The error messages are shown below.

```
[py36] $ spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnny/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnny/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/johnny/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/Users/johnny/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/Users/johnny/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
[johnny:~] [py36] 2s 1 $
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using conda-forge?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba  I don't know what conda forge is.

Comment: Then what's your macOS version?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba  my os version is 10.13.6

Comment: @Roberto - thanks for the edit.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba:  my system is 10.13.6.  Any hints on what to try next to get Spyder to run?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what's happening in your case.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: ok. thank you for looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, more of a workaround I suppose.  I completely deleted my anaconda3 directory and returned to the Anaconda home page and reinstalled anaconda3. Now Spyder runs fine.